# How do I convert freedict file (.dict.dz) to XML?

Tags: linux

I tried to follow the instructions from the "Installation" section of:

https://github.com/freedict/fd-dictionaries

It says "For building make should be enough, at least if you have both tei2slob and xsltproc installed."

xsltproc is already installed on Ubuntu. Don't have any idea about tei2slob. I am just trying to export the dictionary files to plain text. The source files looks like this...

```
# ls -lht
total 20M
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 8.3M Nov 18 03:25 date__2022-01-22_15-16-15Z__8MB.tar.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 1001 docker 6.9M Jan 22 2022 date.dict.dz
-rw-r--r-- 1 1001 docker 2.2M Jan 22 2022 date.idx
-rw-r--r-- 1 1001 docker 136 Jan 22 2022 date.ifo
-rw-r--r-- 1 1001 docker 2.1M Jan 22 2022 date.syn
```

Comment: Download and install https://github.com/itkach/tei2slob

Comment: Not able to install slob. Is docker image available?

Comment: Paste in question the problems you have when you try to install `tei2slob`